# xlrd abre arquivos em formato xls?

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, microsoft-office

desculpa a minha ignorância no assunto, mas estou desenvolvendo um script em Python que leia arquivos de Excel para pegar determinadas informações nesses, e para isso estou usando o xlrd, queria saber se o xlrd é capaz de ler arquivos xls também, que é um formato utilizador pelo Excel mais antigo, alguém poderia me ajudar quanto a isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bom dia, tudo certo?

Como diz na apresentação desta pagina abaixo, é possível sim. Acredito que não tenha diferença pelo menos da parte básica entre .xls e .xlsx com xlrd

[XLRD Download](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd)

Ficaria da seguinte forma:

```
import xlrd #importando a biblioteca

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook('teste.xls') # Escolhe o arquivo a ser lido.

worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0) #Escolha a aba a ser lida. 

for i in range(worksheet.nrows): #itere sobre os itens da aba 
    print(worksheet.row(i))
```

Em meu caso, com esta planilha de entrada :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tenho a seguinte saída, contendo o tipo do valor.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para maiores informações alguns links.

[Lendo arquivos xls com python](https://ark4n.wordpress.com/2009/08/26/lendo-arquivos-xls-com-python/)

[Pagina da biblioteca no Github](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd)

[Lendo dados de uma planilha e enviando um e-mail de aviso XLRD + SMTPLIB](https://github.com/Claudio888/EPI-CONTROL)

Abraço.

Comment: Obrigado amigo, exemplo claro e direto que me foi passado por você, no entanto tenho outra duvida, caso tem como eu saber através de alguma função o numero de numero de "sheets" presentes no documento? Desde ja agradeço a atenção!

Comment: Oi, sem problema. Ja utilizei a função workbook.sheet_names() , ela lista o nome das planilhas, se você armazenar em uma variavel, voce pode usar a função len(nomedalista) e verificar quantos itens tem nela. Abraço

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!